# VB.NET SqlParameter Object Will not accept value of it's value property when coding for a stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

I am creating a function that is used to retrieve a value from a stored procedure.
The code of the stored procedure is as follows:

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_get_drivers_violations_count]
@driver_id int,
@counter int output
As
Begin

Select @counter = Count(fk_violation_id) from link_violations_drivers Where fk_driver_id = @driver_id;
Return @counter;

End
```

The code that I use in my VB.Net program is as follows:

```
  Public Function SpGetDriversViolationsCount2(Id As Int32) As Int32
        Dim SqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = New ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings().MsSqlConString}

        Dim SqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("sp_get_drivers_violations_count", SqlCon)

        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim RetValue As SqlParameter = SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("RetValue", SqlDbType.Int, 11)

        RetValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

        Dim SpParameterId As SqlParameter = SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@driver_id", SqlDbType.Int, 11)

        SpParameterId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

        Dim counter As SqlParameter = SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@counter", SqlDbType.Int, 11)

        counter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        SpParameterId.Value = Id

        Dim ReturnValue As UInt32

        SqlCon.Open()

        Dim DataReader As SqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

        Do While DataReader.Read
            ReturnValue = DataReader.GetInt32(0)
        Loop
        DataReader.Close()

        SqlCon.Close()

        Return ReturnValue

    End Function
```

The code was created using [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308049#bookmark-2) How-To. While trying to debug the function using NUnit, I noticed that the "SpParameterId" object, never get it's value property assigned to a value, even if i explicitly assign a value to it. Thank you.

Comment: So, if you step through that code line by line, after you execute the line `SpParameterId.Value = Id`, what is the value of `SpParameterId.Value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters collection provides access to values returned in output and return value parameters after the call, e.g.,

```
object rv = SqlCmd.Parameters["RetValue"].Value;
```

Note that these values are (according to the tech ref) inaccessible until after the DataReader has been closed.

In practice I usually return scalar values from a stored by selecting them, and then call SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(), just for ease, but that's just a personal preference.